# i am trying to put a label textbox and another label and textbox in a single line using bootstrap but it wouldnot come onthe same line

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

```
 <div class="row">
                              <form class="form-inline">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="tb_FName" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">First Name</asp:Label>
                                    <div class="col-md-10" >
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tb_FName" CssClass="form-control"  />
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="tb_FName"
                                            CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The First Name field is required." SetFocusOnError="True" Display="Dynamic" />
                                    </div>
                         </div>

                            <div class="form-group" style="float:right">
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="tb_LName" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">Last Name</asp:Label>
                                    <div class="col-md-10 ">
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tb_LName" CssClass="form-control"  />
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="tb_LName"
                                            CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The Last Name field is required." SetFocusOnError="True" Display="Dynamic" />
                                   </div>
                                     </div>
                                  </form>
                                    </div>
```

There  is a label and a textbox and another label and textbox .second label and textbox come in the second line.i need to come in the same line.i have put it in a row and used form-inline also..i tried changing the column space still t would  not work.

Comment: Try changing ``class="col-md-10"`` to ``col-md-6`` Bootstrap only has 12 collumns and 10+10 exceeds that limit so pushes it on to the next row

Comment: ya i got it..how to put  a button and textbox in the same vertical line.my button comes way before the textbox in the next line

Comment: Way to Hijack answer but okay - The answer of Shekar also applies to that. just keep the col-md number at or below 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use class= "col-md-3" to set all 3 items in row.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my comment as an answer, before someone else does it....

Change `col-md-10` to `col-md-6` Bootstrap divides the website in grid with 12 columns. You can check [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) for more information about the grid